# How to download all files from Azure Storage using C#?

Tags: c#, download, azure-blob-storage

**I am new bee to Azure Storage**. So, please consider my content in post.
I have a `Azure Storag`e account on which we have `all files stored`. Now, i want to `download` all these `files` to a `folder by looping through each directory and sub directory of the Azure Storage`.

Sample code:

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "photo1.jpg".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("photo1.jpg");

// Save blob contents to a file.
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"path\myfile"))
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
}
```

But i am not able to get **all the 'Container'** and its contents with subcontents.

Help Appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to fetch your container?

Comment: yes! using  IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer> containerslist = blobClient.ListContainers(); Now, jst i want to loop through directory/subdirectory and download all files from azure site.

Answer (score 0):

Use blobClient.[ListContainers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj732202(v=azure.100).aspx)() to get all containers, and use container.[ListBlobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs(v=azure.100).aspx)() to get all blobs in a container.